# A neat pattern in lengths of polygon bisectors

Tags: geometry

All of the polygons here are regular and have side length ${2}$. The multicolored line divides the respective polygon into two equal parts.

[image]

It appears that the formula for any regular polygon with ${n}$ sides where every side has length ${2}$ is:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor} {s_i}^2 =n$$

Does this pattern hold all the way up to infinity? And if so, is there a way to prove it?

*Source: https://twitter.com/BerrySlime3/status/1410568890283806727*

Comment: Someone tweeted a solution in the meantime, btw: https://twitter.com/ilarrosac/status/1421234174137184258 (http://stanwagon.com/public/1325Solution.pdf).

Comment: The problem for me is that this solution seems to only consider regular polygons with an even number of sides.